# Movie involving a cute blonde woman that fights a dragon

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction, fantasy

I'm looking for a movie involving a beautiful blonde woman that fights a dragon. This is what I know about this movie:

**Year**

I watched this movie 2-3 years ago. Its CGI is amazing. I guess it's from 2005++

**Genre**

A sci-fi movie. A little fantasy element is in the movie. It's in color.

**Actor/Actress**

There's not much that I remember about the actor and actress. But, I think there's an actress that looks like Eva Mendez

**Plot**

A man ordered the girl to attack a castle. He's looking for a dragon's nest. The castle is in the mountains. A fire breathing dragon chases the plane in which the man/girl ride.

Well, that's all what I know. I hope you can identify it.

Comment: Sucker Punch indeed, I just rewatched the movie recently. For your reference, Blondie is the nickname of the black haired girl. I think this is in reference to 'dumb blonde' since she isn't the brightest of the bunch. The main character is named Baby Doll.

Comment: I thought the blondie term refer to Babydoll. I don't remember their nickname.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I am sure you're looking for **[Sucker Punch (2011)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0978764/)**

Here's a trailer:

And here's your dragon scene: